# What does the 'Worker' class in InfluxDB do?

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to read up a little bit on InfluxDB and am curious as to what exactly the 'Worker' class does. Link to the documentation here - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/influxdb/0.1.3/InfluxDB/Worker

Are Workers just individual threads that process incoming data batches?